# Connect to Google Analytics from Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, google-analytics

I created a simple SL 4 app to connect to Google Analytics but I keep getting the following exception:

```
{System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at GoogleAnalytics.Silverlight.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetResponseCallback>b__3()}
```

I think it has something to do with xss but I'm not sure how to get around that.  The following code works fine in a console app but doesn't in SL.

The UI has a textblock control, here's the code:

```
private byte[] _data;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string requestData = "Email=email@gmail.com" +
                         "&Passwd=password" +
                         "&source=Test-App" +
                         "&accountType=GOOGLE" +
                         "&service=analytics";

    _data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", UriKind.Absolute));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = _data.Length;

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, request);
}

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
            stream.Write(_data, 0, _data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            textBlock.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    });
}

private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

            textBlock.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "Auth=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            streamReader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            textBlock.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    });
}
```

Update: fixed a typo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight cannot connect to GA services, I either have to use a service or JavaScript then pass the data to Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Just some tipps, i haven't tested your code yet, but they might help.

1. Use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for Web requests, it's much less and cleaner code... You will find [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) <- this link also contains almost all interesting topics on Silverlight Web/http/https requests and security - a must read in your scenario
2. Problems might occur if you're testing from a wrong environment like testing the Silverlight object from a local file url (web Url starting with file:///...). Create a Web-Project in your service, configure the Silverlight Project to run in that created Web project under the Test Web Server or the local IIS

I know, no code examples just links or tipps, they might help you though.

Best regards

**UPDATE**

What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to track, I've seen a few ready solutions for silverlight, for example [Silverlight Analytics](http://silverlightanalytics.codeplex.com/) or [Tracking Silverlight](http://trackingsilverlight.codeplex.com/). Here is another [known solution](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/silverlightTrackingIntro.html).

Comment: 1. tried webclient, less code but still the same issue
2. I have a web project, not browsing files

It seems that the only way to do it is using a service

Comment: Update added... the topic "HTTP Communication Scenarios and Recommended Approaches" in the linked MSDN document wasn't helpful?

Comment: Thanks. I want to build a UI for GA's data, no tracking. But there doesn't seem to be a way to communicate with GA's service because of XSS. The code above is just test code which works in Win/console apps but not in SL. I think I'll have to build a service to get GA's data then pass it to SL to avoid XSS.